# GetOpenIdConnect returns Invalid Credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus, openid-connect, google-oauth

## Context

We are successfully using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth to acquire an `authentication_code` with the following app permissions.

- Know who you are on Google
- View your email address
- View your basic profile info

We are also successfully using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token to exchange that authentication code for an `access_token` and `id_token`.

## Problem

With that `access_token`, we are using https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect to acquire profile information. This is a GET request with the following header.

```
Authorization: Bearer access_token
```

The response from Google is invariably this error:

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
```

[This Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) makes two suggestions:

- Refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token.
- If this fails, direct the user through the OAuth flow, as described in Authorizing Your App with Google Drive.

We have tried both of those approaches and receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

We were accidentally using the `id_token` in the Authorization header. We needed to make sure to use the `access_token` instead.

Comment: Saved my life! I have wasted almost whole day for that. All this is so much complicated and the docs are common. Using Google APIs is a small hell.